# How to create handsome looking glossy characters in Blender

Tags: rendering, texturing, objects, light, image

I am just another version of you as Indians say.
And this version of you needs some enlightening badly.

I am trying to create nice and glossy character made sort of black reflective none transparent cristal.
Something like this fellow here
[image]

But view port preview or rendered pictures alike turn out as grey or none reflective, simply looking horrible.

I don't know if it is light, need for something to reflect around the object or the object material settings but something is not just right. It feels like there is a simple fix to it. Would you know how to do it?

The look for faces I am looking as per image
[image]

Adding some images of my set up

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: This question needs some details, like a reference image of what you're trying to achieve and your current setup: nodes or scene. Non-transparent cristal sounds like an oxymoron. It seems you just need to decrease roughness of your Principled BSDF shader node? Also a typical mistake with reflective materials is having nothing around the object to be reflected.

Comment: you could do it with a glossy material and you need a HDRI picture to have a better result, and of course flat shading and the topology is important

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I've included screen shot from my project. Hope it helps.

Comment: @moonboots Tried different HDRIs, shade smooth, different types of lights direct of reflecting from a surface. There is something i simply dont get here but I feel the solution is near

Comment: please pack your images and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: you need to put the Metallic value at 1

Comment: https://pasteall.org/media/b/9/b9e1baacd0585b2c012ec77c066b4196.blend

Comment: I suggest playing with your lighting setup, too. This *appears* to be back-lit, whereas your reference image is lit from the front. I would also encourage, given that you aren't going for physically-based rendering, playing with your emission color and strength a bit.

Comment: Your mesh is flat. A cristal is not flat, that is, what you mean by cristal is a structure of multiple flat surfaces with hard edges and corners. But multiple flat surfaces all with the same normals (parallel to each-other) and touching each other is really just one surface. I think instead of going through specific tutorials on this problem, you should first go through some basic modelling tutorials. Also modelling an owl is rather hard for a first project.

Comment: I've edited my answer and tried something with your file, as close as possible to what you show, as Markus says, the problem is that your object is flat, but maybe my solution will fit your needs?

Comment: @moonboots yes, thanks a lot to you! My mistake was as Markus von Broady pointed out is that I used flat version of my owl :) Even though I have the one with proper topology :) White trying to find a solution I have made too many copies of the same thing and simply was trying fix the wrong one. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a try, create a low-poly object, give it a material with *Metalic* value at 1 and *Glossy* at 0, give your world an HDRI so that your object has something to reflect:

[image]

As Markus says, your object is actually completely flat, so what you could do is first create more topology (perhaps with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to triangulate) then select some vertices (for example with Select > Select Random, then play with the factor in the *Operator* box), then move this vertices on the Y axis so that they can reflect the HDRI image. Don't forget to put the *Metallic* value at 1. Here is what it can give:

[image]

Comment: I gave it a try but still no good. I looked through several tutorials on plastic surfaces and other reflective objects but the result I am looking for is nowhere to be seen.

Comment: @Pro I feel like the result you were looking for has been achieved in this answer. Modifying the question afterwards is not really fair to the people trying to answer it. :) The tools to achieve your look have been laid out : Use flat shading, use a correct lighting setup, and use a metallic material. (And a 3D model...)

Comment: @Pro: i totally agree with Gorgious. And what you also think about is: YOU want help and moonboots took the time to give you a good and time consuming answer. So you should check the checkmark left to his answer and then ask another question, if you question "changes" all of a sudden. And if you behave like you did - it might happen that people here are not willing anymore to help you (and believe me, you will regret this).

Comment: I don't think he means any harm, it's just that going from 2D to 3D is a complete jump to another way of doing things so it may be a bit disturbing  ;)

Comment: Thanks again moonboots.